# CoreUI icons from npm not showing in ReactJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I've installed @coreui/icons with npm install --save successfully, but now that I make a div or span or anything with class as suggested here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coreui/icons, nothing shows up.

I'm developing a project with React, if that matters.

So in my component's render function I have:

```
render() {
    return(<div>
        <i className="cui-energy"></i>
        <i class="cui-energy"></i>
    </div>)
}
```

But literally nothing is showing. Do I need to import a css file or anything for it to work?

Comment: The energy icon isn't included in the freely available ones; trying the twitter icon and including the stylesheet worked for me.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact code?

Comment: I included the three stylesheets found [here](https://coreui.io/docs/3.0-beta/icons/introduction/) in my `public/index.html` and used `<i className="cib-twitter" />`: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hertz-xesgx

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did get that to work as well, however I could only get the brand icons to show, even trying the ones that I believe to be Free. What I really wanted though was to use it through npm, as it's instructed that you can install it in that way there must be a way to.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too. No idea how you're supposed to use the npm package; it does contain all the files, but it's not a module, as far as I can tell. There's nothing to `import` there, unlike for instance with [material UI](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons) icons. Even if you linked manually to the CSS file, that would only be good for a locally run server. I don't see how you'd deploy this solution elsewhere without copying around the required files. It seems like the package is simply offered as an alternative to downloading and extracting `master.zip`?